# debugging curl - there is a 8 second timeout

Tags: linux, curl

I am seeing a 8 second timeout any time I curl to my node.js webserver. How can i test this? The server does not receive the request until the end, and the times are all around 8.1 second, so it's pretty clear something is timing out at 8s.

The request succeeds. It happens for POSTs and GETs.

I have tried `-4`.

Comment: Random stab in the dark: is everything on the way IPv6 enabled? Maybe some request (DNS  lookup or the GET itself) is tried to the IPv6 first and waits for some timeout there. You could also try running `strace curl ...` and see if it hangs in a system call.

Comment: Ah, good ol' strace. I'd not had the opportunity to use it yet.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Is there some way I can intersperse some prints in the strace every 0.1 second perhaps? How am i gonna be able to tell which calls hung?

Comment: well, I was kindof hoping that your 8-second delay would manifest itself in one system call, so you could just ctrl-c by hand when curl hangs there and look what was last.

Comment: Oh, also, `man strace` suggest that the `-r` option will print a relative timestamp, the `-tt` option will print absolute timestamps and `-T` will show the time spent in system calls. I've not tried any of this, but maybe one of these options is useful.

Comment: Hm. Appears to be a machine configuration problem. Ping has a similar delay and barely works, either.

Answer (score 0):

Blaming the corporate firewall. (this is a VM under NAT that is exhibiting the problem)